# How to draw a regular hexagon on a map?

Tags: algorithm, gis, graph-algorithm

I hava many Point. I need to draw the regular hexagon that the point belongs to according to the point.Multiple points can fall within the same hexagon.But hexagons cannot overlap or gap.

Now I find `uber h3`.But he cannot guarantee the drawing of regular hexagons.

This is the rendering:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why H3 are not regular hexagons: Uber's H3 is designed to cover whole globe. There is no way to cover spherical Earth with regular (or even arbitrary) hexagons (H3 has 12 pentagons).

So first thing you need to decide is what's the scope of your application? If it is global, and you want to use single grid, you have to drop regular hexagons requirements and use something like H3.

If the scope of you application is local and you are using a single projection, you can tile it with regular hexagons using basic math, much simpler than H3 computations.